# How to force redirect query string URL with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect `example.com/recipes/signup?code=OLD277` to `example.com/recipes-user/register` How can I achieve it via htacces?

I tried the below code in `.htaccess` but its not working!

```
Redirect /recipes/signup?code=OLD277 http://example.com/recipes-user/register
```

Comment: If you visit `http://example.com/recipes-user/register` in browser, does it show correct page?

Comment: Yes it shows a registration page. @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule as your topmost rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /recipes/signup\?code=OLD277\s [NC]
RewriteRule . /recipes-user/register? [R=301,L,NE]
```